# Amplitude of $e^-+\gamma\to e^-+\pi^0$ scattering in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, probability

#### The exercise

The goal is to compute the transition probability of the process $$e^-+\gamma\to e^-+\pi^0 $$ according to the interaction Lagrangian $\mathcal L=g\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\mu A_\nu\partial_\rho A_\sigma\varphi-e\bar\psi\gamma^\tau\psi A_\tau$.

Since this is the first time I do an exercise of this kind, I'd like to post it here in the hope of receiving tips and eventual corrections; hopefully it can also help others who are looking for similar exercises, as I haven't found many of this kind floating around the web.

#### The (pedantic) solution

Let $(\mathbf p_1,r)$, $(\mathbf p_2,s)$ be the momenta and polarizations of the input and output electrons, $\mathbf k_1$ and $\alpha$ the momentum and polarization of the photon, and lastly $\mathbf k_2$ the momentum of the pion. The initial and final states are then $$|\text{in}\rangle=b^\dagger(\mathbf p_1, r)a^\dagger(\mathbf k_1, \alpha)|0\rangle, \quad \langle \text{out}|=\langle 0|b(\mathbf p_2,s)c(\mathbf k_2)$$
where $a^\dagger, b^\dagger, c$ satisfy the correct (anti-)commutation rules for fermions and bosons respectively. Using these states, we need to compute the transition amplitude
$$A=\langle\text{out}|T[\exp(iS)]|\text{in}\rangle. $$

Since the process involves four particles while the Lagrangian contains two terms with only three fields, the first non-zero order in the expansion of the scattering matrix $T[\exp(i S)]$ is the second one. Concretely, only the double product of the terms contributes to the amplitude, as the squares of each term do not contain all the fields necessary for the contractions with the ladder operators defined above. Thus, the amplitude is
\begin{align*}
A=\langle 0|b(\mathbf p_2,s)c(\mathbf k_2)\left(ge\int d^4x d^4y T[\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\mu A_\nu(x) \partial_\rho A_\sigma(x)\varphi(x)\cdot \bar\psi(y)\gamma^\tau\psi(y)A_\tau(y)]\right)b^\dagger(\mathbf p_1, r)a^\dagger(\mathbf k_1, \alpha)|0\rangle.
\end{align*}
and the associated Feynman diagram is

[image]

The contractions of the electronic and the pionic operators are all fixed, as there is one and only one field containing the corresponding non-commuting operator; on the other hand, there are *a priori* three different contractions for the photonic operator. Therefore, we have
$$A=(ge)\int d^4xd^4y \underbrace{b(\mathbf p_2,s)\bar\psi(y)}\gamma^\tau\underbrace{b^\dagger(\mathbf p_1, r)\psi(y)}\overbrace{\varphi(x)c(\mathbf k_2)}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}[\text{photon contractions} ],$$
where as per the above
$$\text{photon contractions}=\underbrace{a^\dagger\partial_\mu A_\nu(x)}\overbrace{\partial_\rho A_\sigma(x) A_\tau(y)}+\underbrace{a^\dagger\partial_\rho A_\sigma(x)}\overbrace{\partial_\mu A_\nu(x) A_\tau(y)}+\underbrace{a^\dagger A_\tau(y)}\overbrace{\partial_\mu A_\nu(x)\partial_\rho A_\sigma(x)}. $$
Of these three terms, the last is zero as the propagator is between two fields evaluated in the same point, and the other two are actually the same, as the Levi-Civita tensor is invariant under exchange of the two pair of indexes $(\mu,\rho)$ and $(\sigma,\tau)$. Thus
$$\text{photon contractions}= 2\underbrace{a^\dagger(\mathbf k_1,\alpha)\partial_\mu A_\nu(x)}\overbrace{\partial_\rho A_\sigma(x) A_\tau(y)}.$$

Let us go over each contraction in detail, reminding ourselves of the explicit form of the fields:
\begin{align*}
\overbrace{b(\mathbf p_2,s)\bar\psi(y)}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{p_2}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt V}\bar u(\mathbf p_2, s)e^{ip_2y}
\\
\overbrace{b^\dagger(\mathbf p_1, r)\psi(y)}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{p_1}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt V}u(\mathbf p_1,r)e^{-ip_1y}
\\
\overbrace{\varphi(x)c(\mathbf k_2)}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{k_2}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt V}e^{ik_2x}
\\
\overbrace{a^\dagger(\mathbf k_1,\alpha)\partial_\mu A_\nu(x)}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2|\mathbf k_1|}}\frac{1}{\sqrt V}\epsilon_\nu(\mathbf k_1,\alpha)e^{-ik_1x}(-i(k_1)_\mu)
\\
\overbrace{\partial_\rho A_\sigma(x) A_\tau(y)}&=-i\partial_\rho\int \frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4}e^{-iq(x-y)}\frac{\eta^{\sigma\tau}}{q^2}=-\int \frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4}q_\rho e^{-iq(x-y)}\frac{\eta^{\sigma\tau}}{q^2}.
\end{align*}
Now that we've got everything, let's substitute back into the amplitude:
$$A=\frac{2ige}{4V^2\sqrt{E_{p_1}E_{p_2}|\mathbf k_1|E_{k_2}}}\int d^4xd^4y \ e^{i(k_2-k_1-q)x}e^{i(p_2-p_1+q)y}\int \frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{q^2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\bar u(\mathbf p_2,s)\gamma_\sigma u(\mathbf p_1,r)q_\rho\epsilon_\nu(\mathbf k_1,\alpha)(k_1)_\mu$$ where we made use of the fact that $\gamma^\tau\eta_{\sigma\tau}=\gamma_\sigma$. Now we simply consider that
$$\int d^4xd^4y \ e^{i(k_2-k_1-q)x}e^{i(p_2-p_1+q)y}=(2\pi)^4\delta^4(p_f-p_i)(2\pi)^4\delta^4(k_2-k_1-q)$$ and use the second delta to kill the $d^4q$ integral by setting $q=k_2-k_1$; the first delta gives instead the correct conservation of four-momentum. Therefore,
$$A=\frac{ige(2\pi)^4\delta^4(p_f-p_i)}{2V^2\sqrt{E_{p_1}E_{p_2}|\mathbf k_1|E_{k_2}}} \frac{\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(k_1)_\mu\epsilon_\nu(\mathbf k_1,\alpha)\bar u(\mathbf p_2,s) u(\mathbf p_1,r)q_\rho\gamma_\sigma}{(k_2-k_1)^2}$$ is the desired amplitude. Is this result correct?

Comment: Looks fine on the face of it. One tends to discourage "check my work" questions, as no reader but the OP is liable to learn from them. You might write down this tree Feynman diagram involving each of your two vertices once , to help yourself and the reader...

Comment: For photoproduction of pions, $\gamma + e^-\rightarrow \pi^0 + e^-$ is clearer to experimentalist. Now if you don't detect the final state electron (but use kinematics to verify it), the reaction is written $e^-(\gamma, \pi^0)e^-$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks! I've added the diagram that I think is correct, though somewha disproportionate to the rest of the answer. I've thought of a way to make this less of a "check my work" question: it seems to be that computing the square of $A$ (in order to find, for example, the cross section) would be quite complicated. Is that a calculation worth doing, or just a mess of spinors and tensors?

Comment: @JEB Ok, thanks for the tip. I prefer the less compact but clearer notation!

Comment: Yes, good diagram. Most experts, not I, immediately write your answer by mere inspection of it. The gamma matrix should be sandwiched by the spinors.

Comment: That's something I'm struggling to understand. We've been doing things with Wick contractions, treating the diagrams as an afterthought. But I know that for every theory (QED most notably) one can write down rules to turn the diagram into the correct mathematics. I assume this can also be done for my own Lagrangian. May I ask why the experts can do that, but you can't? You are very much an expert in my eyes.

Comment: Oh, I'm an expert, but I haven't done industrial scale calculations for a while.

Comment: The invariant matrix element (your amplitude without the trivial factors in front) is indeed $2 i ge \epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} k_{1 \mu} \epsilon(k_1) \bar{u}(p_2) \gamma_\sigma u(p_1) q_\rho /q^2$, where I have suppressed all spin (polarization) indices. If you wish, you may replace $q_\rho$ by $k_{2 \rho}$ as $\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} k_{1 \mu} k_{1 \rho}= 0$. Squaring the invariant matrix element, summing (averaging, respectively) over the spins and finally computing the cross section is now very simple. Try it!

Comment: @Hyperon I'm actually having some trouble with that exact calculation. The trick I've seen before is to consider the terms with $\mu,\rho,\sigma=0$ respectively (as $\nu$ contracts with $\epsilon_\nu$, it must be spatial), and try to write everything as a scalar/cross product of vectors. It doesn't seem to work well in this case though...